# Specify defaults for imported services in Symfony Container

Tags: symfony

We have the following

```
imports:
    - {...yml}
    - {...yml}

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
```

However this default isn't applying to the services we import as we wanted it to. Are we required to define the defaults in every imported yml file containing services?

The contents of these yml files looks like

```
services:
    '...' etc
```

Comment: Can you explain all that further? Which default is not applied? How exactly does that service section look like in the imported files?

Comment: To answer your question, yes you have to define the defaults in every individual yaml file.  It's just the way the system was defined.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is not possible.

**`_defaults` apply only to services defined in that particular config**. 
Not to external services and `imports`.

For more, see [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#service-container-services-load-example). Especially **line 3** comment:

[image]